# Bootstrap or Material Design Lite or Both

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design-lite

I am creating websites from last 6-7 years and Using Bootstrap since Bootstrap 2 is launched and love to use bootstrap 3.

Now I am trying to use Google Material Design Lite, so My Question is
"Do I need to use Bootstrap framework for using Material Design Lite or I can use Material Design alone, will it give good responsive website and grid system like bootstrap does?"

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Consider reading the documentation for Material Design Lite and see what it says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both together, however, I do not advise you to do so. I haven't tested myself.

Remember that MDL does not replace every TBS component, instead it has its own approach, that said, do not expect it to include everything that you're used to have with TBS.

An Alternative approach would using: 

1. [Material Design for Bootstrap](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) - Free

2. [MDB](http://mdbootstrap.com/) - Free is limited, but the Pro version is extended.